# Battery Power output

Tags: batteries, dc

If  a battery has 100mA-hour rating will two batteries connected in series have also 100mA-hour rating but at double the voltage?

Answer (score 0):

If identical batteries are connected in series, the Ampere-hour rating of the series group is the same as the A-H rating of one battery.

If identical batteries are connected in parallel, the resulting A-H rating is the sum of the individual battery ratings.

Comment: I agree but would point out there are some other factors which make it less simple.